# UISwitch between radian and degrees mode for Swift Calculator

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

I've been following the Stanford Swift Tutorials, and I have a working solution for most of the tasks.

However, I want to implement a UISwitch function that enables radian/degree mode.

I already made the function, but I can't seem to find a way to get it to work - it keeps giving me the radian default answers, instead of the degree.

Please help me improve the code

**CalculatorEngine.swift**

```
// this is the conversion function
func sind(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    return sin(degrees * 180 / M_PI)
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var switch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet weak var labelDisplay: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
}




// this function is supposed to call conversion function once switch is On
    @IBAction func switchTogOnOff(sender: UISwitch) {
        for button5 in [radButton, degButton] {
            button5.hidden = !button5.hidden
        }

        if mySwitch.on {
            engine.sind(displayValue)

        }   
        else {
            displayValue = 0
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do that, one way would be to declare a transform factor in your `CalculatorEngine`

```
var unitTransformFactor: Double = 1
```

and change its value when you switch between degrees and radians

```
@IBAction func switchTogOnOff(sender: UISwitch) {
   ...

   var degreesSelected: Bool = mySwitch.on

   // there are better ways to write to do this but it will work
   self.engine.unitTransformFactor = degreesSelected ? M_PI / 180 : 1.0
}
```

Then you can declare your math operations in your engine as

```
func sinOperation(angle: Double) -> Double {
   return sin(angle * self.unitTransformFactor)
}

func asinOperation(value: Double) -> Double {
   return asin(value) / self.unitTransformFactor
}
```

and use them as:

```
knownOps["sin"] = Op.UnaryOperation("sin", sinOperation)
...
knownOps["sin⁻¹"] = Op.UnaryOperation("sin⁻¹", asinOperation)
```

By the way, your `sind` function doesn't work properly, you have to multiply degrees by `M_PI` and divide by `180` not the other way around.

Comment: @ash added outline. I did not test it but it should work.

Comment: @ash I think I have fixed that now.

Comment: @ash If units are radians, the new code does nothing (`unitTransformFactor` is `1`, we are just multiplying/diving by `1`). If units are degrees, multiplying by  `unitTransformFactor` converts degrees to radians (`radians  = degrees * M_PI / 180`). That's basically it.

Comment: Also, asin, acos and tan doesnt seem to work -   also, deg mode cos(90) returns 6.123, where it should return 0. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @ash No, you just have to add the same code that you have added for `sin` also for `cos`, `tan`, `acos` and `atan`.

Comment: Is there another method for asin, atan and acos, because they are not really working. The normal sin, cos tan work fine however. U mentioned "there are better ways to write to do this but it will work"

Comment: @ash Don't worry about that mention, that was more about coding style than functionality. Could you tell me your input value and your `asin` result?

Comment: Real Calculator - Asin(45) = Error.                                                                In my calculator, Asin(45) = 0.9033.

Comment: @ash `asin` is a function that takes values between -1 and 1. It does not take angles, Trying value `45` on it makes no sense and it will lead to undefined results. `asin(1) = 90 degrees`

Comment: Alright, then 90 cos in my calculator gives me 6.123 in deg mode.   It's supposed to be 0.  that's the only problem with the main sin/cos/tan in deg mode.

Comment: Edited the question - code is at bottom of the Code sample for View Controller - really for Calculator Engine.

Comment: @ash I am pretty sure `cos` will never return a value bigger than `1` so if you are getting `6.123`, you are probably calling a whole different function from you operation.

Comment: It works perfectly, except for when I try cos(90) in deg mode